# The list view is not shown fragment

Tags: android, listview

I created a fragment where I added a listView. Created an adapter but the list viewis not shown in the fragment.

```
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

// Inflate the layout for this

String[] songArray={"Song 1","Song 2","Song 3","Song 4","Song 5","Song 6","Song 7"};

    hindi= (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.hindiList);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(),R.layout.textdesign,R.id.textView2,songArray);

    hindi.setAdapter(adapter);


    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hindi, container, false);
}
```

Comment: getView() makes no sense inside the onCreateView().

Comment: I believe you are getting NPE, as under `onCreateView` view is not created and you are trying to access it with `getView()`.. follow @SagarTrehan answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    String[] songArray={"Song 1","Song 2","Song 3","Song 4","Song 5","Song 6","Song 7"};

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hindi, container, false);
    ListView hindiListView = (ListView) rootView1.findViewById(R.id.hindiList);
    ListAdapter hindiAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.textDesign, songArray);
    hindiListView.setAdapter(hindiAdapter);
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added **List view id** like this

```
<ListView
  android:id="@id/android:list"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

While setting adapter , insert this line . For example :

```
 getListView().setAdapter(new ListAdapter(getActivity(), rowItems));
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the `onCreateView` implementation with below snippet:

```
@Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    // Inflate the layout for this
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hindi, container, false);
    String[] songArray={"Song 1","Song 2","Song 3","Song 4","Song 5","Song 6","Song 7","Song 8"};
    hindi= (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.hindiList);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(),R.layout.textdesign,R.id.textView2,songArray);
    hindi.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: What I changed: 1. See the return value. 2. See how I am retrieving listview object.

Answer (score -1):

Try below code

```
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hindi, container, false); 
    hindi= (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.hindiList);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(),R.layout.textdesign,R.id.textView2,songArray);
        hindi.setAdapter(adapter);


        return view;
```

Comment: CAn you add xml file